# Computation of two Dask arrays freezing at the end

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have generated two random dask arrays of length 450,000,000 that I want to divide by each other. When I go to compute them, the calculation always freezes at the end.

I have an 8 core 32GB instance running to run the code.

I have tried the code below and some modification that I've tried is not persisting the data in x or y.

```
x = da.random.random(450000000, chunks=(10000,))
x = client.persist(x)
z1 = dd.from_array(x)

y = da.random.random(450000000, chunks=(10000,))
y = client.persist(y)
z2 = dd.from_array(y)

flux_ratio_sq = z1.div(z2)
flux_ratio_sq.compute()
```

Actual results I am getting is that the persist holds the x and y in memory (total of 8GB of memory) which is expected and then compute adds more to memory. Some errors I'm getting are below.

A lot of these errors:

```
distributed.core - INFO - Event loop was unresponsive in Scheduler for 
3.74s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions 
or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.

tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback <bound method 
BokehTornado._keep_alive of <bokeh.server.tornado.BokehTornado 
object at 0x7fb48562a4a8>>

raise StreamClosedError(real_error=self.error)
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed
```

I want the final result to be in a dask Series so I can merge it with my existing data.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I'm trying on a local machine with 16GB of memory so I'm using `N=4.5e7` instead of `N=4.5e8` and I found that: 1) it seems to perform in the same way even if you don't persist. 2) Using `flux_ratio_sq = da.divide(x,y)` is 2x faster than using series.

Comment: I must have been encountering some issue with loading into a dataframe and then doing the calculations. Using da.divide(x,y) solved the problem. If you want to repost your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to "accept" you answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to expand my comment here. Fist: given than `numpy` performs better than `pandas` (`DataFrame` or `Series`) it is better to do your calculation using numpy and then append the result to a `DataFrame` if is needed. With `Dask` it is exactly the same. Second following the [documentation](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-performance.html) you should persist only in case you need to call the same dataframe several times.

So for your specific problem what you could do is

```
import dask.array as da
N = int(4.5e7)

x = da.random.random(N, chunks=(10000,))
y = da.random.random(N, chunks=(10000,))
flux_ratio_sq = da.divide(x, y).compute()
```

Addendum: with a `dask.dataframe` you could use `to_parquet()` instead of `compute()` and have your results stored to file. In embarrassingly parallel problems like this one the impact on RAM is less than using `compute()`. It will be interesting to know if something similar could apply in case of `dask.array`